# MFC form designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

According to my understanding if I need design MFC form with button I have only one possibility - write everything in code editor. There is no designer. Except cases when I need design dialog form. I can use designer and generate resources for dialogs. But in case normal Frame there is possibility to drop buttons in designer window. Is that truth?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a form as a main window, create your project with a `CFormView` as a base class. You can select that inside the new project wizard. Then you get a dialog resource for that view. It works just like a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Resource view
2. Create a new dialog template
3. Double click the dialog template name
4. Once the dialog opens, the toolbox get enabled
5. You can drag&drop the controls to the form now